# Understanding AWS cache key for specific scenario

Tags: caching, key, amazon-cloudfront, aws-policies

Imagine the following scenario:

A customer is using AWS CloudFront and is serving a site that expects and ordinarily receives no query strings. Essentially the entire site is static and the CDN is purely enabling performance by caching and distributing the content.

On occasion, we as a solutions provider for the customer, wish to refresh any page (JavaScript) on the customer site and within that refresh request, append a query string with parameter values that will be unique to each visitor. This event will only happen once per visitor in a set period - say for argument's sake, 365 days.

With the existing cache configuration, the cache can be busted and performance affected when x new visitors (x being sizeable) come to the site and trigger the refresh event.

I wish to understand how we can configure the cache key to send any page request with our query string included, to the origin but not store it in the cache once served. The cache should only store the page when the static URL is requested not the dynamic URL (dynamic because our query string has been included) when it is requested.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify which query strings to be included in the cache key or not, have a look at this document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/controlling-the-cache-key.html#cache-policy-query-strings. With **include specified query strings** cache behaviour cloudfront will send the request to origin with query strings and than you probably want your origin to send cache header as no-cache so cloudfront will not cache.

Comment: Thanks @user15558255. Can the cache key support regex for the query string (which will have dynamic parameter values). How would the origin send a cache header for the full URL, of which the query string is the only dynamic element?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't support regex you have do add individual querystring to whitelist it. May be you can elaborate more on what you are trying achieve ? are you worried about some customer are served with stale content ? or you worried about javascriot is not updated ?

Comment: Lets say the customer has all content cached - using the cdn as a loadbalancer essentially. Our JavaScript code, for once per user in 365 days will refresh the page and include a query string. This query string will have the same parameters but the values will be dynamic. Currently, when the customer runs our code and when there are many visitors triggering this event (their first visit) it is blowing up the cache. I am trying to understand how to mitigate this. I assumed Cache keys would be the option, perhaps I am wrong or missing something?

Comment: If you want to serve newer javascript, then  you should probably consider versioning javascript files. and reference new javascript files with the new deployed code,